# Что означает ~$ в терминале bash (в начале строки)?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Что означает ~$ в терминале bash (в начале строки)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выводим значение переменной PS1 (primary prompt string):

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

Разбираем специальные символы:

- `\u` - The username of the current user.
- `\h` - The hostname, up to the first ‘.’.
- `\w` - The current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde.
- `\$` - If the effective uid is 0, #, otherwise $.

В итоге `~$` означает пользователя в домашней директории.

Источник: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Answer (score 6):

Это стандартное приглашение командной оболочки. Оно хранится в переменной окружения с именем PS1 и может быть в любой момент заменена на другое. По умолчанию слева от знака доллара располагается информация о пути к текущему каталогу. Тильда означает, что вы находитесь в домашней директории текущего пользователя. Подробнее [тут](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_base/node133.html)

Comment: Тильда - домашний каталог, ок. А что знак доллара означает?

Comment: По большому счету это просто разделитель. Он отделяет путь к директории от вводимой команды

Comment: А как он называется? Хочу про него прочитать в мануале: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Comment: @Hipster Так почитайте в этом мануале про PS1, про который сказано в ответе "_If the effective uid is 0, #, otherwise $._"

Comment: @Mike Вот, значит это никакой не разделитель: $ - означает пользователя, # - суперпользователя.

Comment: то есть root - имеющий все права

Comment: Можно настроить приглашение по желанию http://blablacode.ru/linux/21

Comment: Это не отменяет того, что он играет роль обычного разделителя. Как я уже сказал он хранится в переменной окружения. А переменные окружения разные для каждого пользователя. Когда ты запускаешь терминал от имени супер пользователя, то этот символ отображается из ходя из настроек окружения супер пользователя и тебе ничто не мешает сделать его таким же как и у обычного пользователя

Comment: @КузьминАлексей Ещё как отменяет, $ - это не разделитель! А кастомизация тут вообще ни при чём.

Comment: @Hipster: `$` это часть prompt (приглашения). То что на некоторых системах в `/etc/profile` может быть написано: `if [ "\`id -u\`" -eq 0 ]; then PS1='# '; else PS1='$ '; fi` (поэтому для root вы видите `#`) вовсе не значит, что PS1 не может быть изменена. К примеру, у меня `echo $PS1` выводит `$(virtualenv_prompt_info)%{%}%{$fg[green]%}%c \
$(git_prompt_info)\
\
%{$fg[red]%}%(!.#.»)%{$reset_color%}`

Comment: @jfs Причём здесь изменения то? Я же не про кастомизацию спрашиваю.

Comment: @Hipster вы сказали: # означает "суперпользователя" -- я говорю: PS1 может поменяться (что значит что, вы можете увидеть # даже если вы не root, и наоборот: даже если вы root, вы не обязаны # видеть). Иначе говоря, нельзя утверждать, что # означает root, PS1 может и меняется на практике.

Comment: @jfs Как вывести текущее значение PS1?

Comment: @Hipster явно `echo $PS1` команда выше упомянута.

Comment: @Hipster а если не секрет, какая цель вопроса и последующих препинаний?