# xfce4-terminal в одну строчку

Tags: linux, консоль

xfce4-terminal выглядит следующим образом

```
user@pc:~
$
```

Тоесть в две строчки. как сделать xfce4-terminal в одну строчку, как на всех linux? MX Linux

Comment: уберите перевод строки из [переменной `$PS1`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/725868/178576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вид приглашения берется из переменной окружения PS1. Можно прописать в ~/.bashrc нужный Вам вид. Но, вообще, двустрочное приглашение самое удобное, как показывает практика. К примеру, как выглядит кусок моего файла, за это отвечающий (честно взято из какого-то древнего блога сто лет назад):

```
INPUT_COLOR="\[\033[0m\]"
DIR_COLOR="\[\033[0;33m\]"
DIR="\w"
 
LINE_VERTICAL="\342\224\200"
LINE_CORNER_1="\342\224\214"
LINE_CORNER_2="\342\224\224"
LINE_COLOR="\[\033[0;37m\]"
 
USER_NAME="\[\033[0;32m\]\u"
SYMBOL="\[\033[0;32m\]$"
 
if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then
    USER_NAME="\[\033[0;31m\]\u"
    SYMBOL="\[\033[0;31m\]#"
fi
 
PS1="$LINE_COLOR$LINE_CORNER_1$LINE_VERTICAL $USER_NAME $DIR_COLOR$DIR \n$LINE_COLOR$LINE_CORNER_2$LINE_VERTICAL $SYMBOL $INPUT_COLOR"
```

Если вы просто хотите в одну строчку, то можете просто написать
`PS1="\u@\h \W\$ "`. Пояснение по специальным символам (на всякий случай): \u - имя пользователя, \h - имя машины, \W - Ваша текущая директория. В целом советую более читаемый формат `PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "`.